# Material 2 dialog change style

Tags: css, angular-material2

I'm trying to change the style of the md-dialog.

in my main.scss i'm importing the prebuild pink-bluegrey theme...
then in my component I import the following -->

```css
@import "@angular/material/dialog/dialog.scss";

$mat-dialog-padding: 0;
$mat-dialog-border-radius: 0.5rem;
$background: #ffffff;

@mixin mat-dialog-container {
    padding: $mat-dialog-padding;
    border-radius: $mat-dialog-border-radius;
    background: $background;
}

@include mat-dialog-container;
```

The padding and border radius is correctly applied to the dialog window. 
But the background is not working... also tried the !important statement.

I'm using this in a single component... 
Is there also a change to apply those styles globally?

in chrome dev tools I see those applied style changes. The background gets overwritten by the pink-bluegrey theme..

hope anyone can help.

thanks

Answer (score 22):

It is better practice to add a wrapper class around your dialog, and then add styling to the children. [Have a look at this article](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) for more information.

When you open your Angular dialog, you can add a `panelClass`
 attribute, like this:

`this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {panelClass: 'my-panel'})`.

then, in your css (e.g. in the root styles.css file), you can add the following:

```
.my-panel .mat-dialog-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**EDIT** *Warning*

It is also possible to add the css to another file than the root styles.css, but then you have to use `::ng-deep` in the css (e.g. `::ng-deep .my-panel{ // ... }`). This is not advised, as `::ng-deep` is [deprecated in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

**EDIT2** *Good alternative*

If you are using scss, then you can place your `.my-panel`-style in your mydialog.component.scss file, by using a `@mixin`, and `@import` the file in styles.scss. You can then use `@include` to load the defined mixin.

in your mydialog.component.scss file

```
@mixin myPanel(){
 .my-panel .mat-dialog-container {
   // css here
 }
}
```

in your styles.scss

```
@import 'path/to/mydialog.component.scss' // you don't need the .scss suffix

@include myPanel();
```

Comment: is there any way to encapsualte the style in a non-global css? Hard to re-use the dialog this way, if you must insert stuff into the app's root css.

Comment: Yes, you can add it in the dialog’s css file:  e.g ‘mydialog.component.css’

Comment: it is not working for me :S Isn't mat.dialog-container is actually 2 levels higher than the actual element though? So I guess it should be somewhere higher?

Comment: Ok, then I need to check how I did it in our application, but cannot do that until next week. If you are using sass or less, you could create a separate file, and include it in your main .scss file.

Comment: I had a look at our code, and we keep the css inside the `mydialog.component.css`, but we use the ::ng-deep notation. e.g. `::ng-deep .my-panel{ // ... } `

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecating, I would definitely go with the panel class option in the style.css. Plus using 
::ng-deep causes some weird unexpected behavior across the App.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by including this css block in the end of file **material2-app-theme.scss**

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can you use css then change background in mat dilog, at i used color transparent

```
 mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
  }
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.