# Changing mat-dialog backgroundcolor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the background color of angular mat-dialog. I get it to work with

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

on a global scale, but when I try to only do it locally I can't change the color, only width for example. Is this by design, or is it something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you please add code from your styles as well to understand how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49936605/2358409